# Spring Firebase cloud messaging connection Auth fails

Tags: spring, firebase, authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I work with firebase for the first time and I am a bit confused about the usage of the cloud messaging.

**Environment:**

I have a Spring Microservice that should send messages ( data not notification) to apps by their token. ( platform independant)
As protocol I want to use the recommended Http v1.

I created a firebase account, added a test project und now I want to pust data there. 
As far as I've read there is no way the see the message pushed for debugging?

I have no App to test the flow because it will be developed by externaly.

**Current behaviour:**

```
 I just want to create a first test message. Therefor I use the following code. 
    // myProject from settings- general->ProjectID
    String FIREBASE_API_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myProject/messages:send";
    // From settings->cloud-messaging
        String FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY = "newServerKey";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("Authorization", "Bearer" + FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY);
    httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    message.put("title","Hallo");
    message.put("body","TEst");


    json.put("data", message);
//I was hoping that this has not to be a valid token for testing. 
    json.put("to", "receiverFcmKey");

    System.out.println("Sending :" + json.toString());

    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json.toString(), httpHeaders);
    for(int i =0; i<1; i++) {
        System.out.println("Count:"+ i);
        System.out.println(restTemplate.postForObject(FIREBASE_API_URL, httpEntity, String.class));
}
```

Here I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
```

[Here](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/cloud-messaging-test-7bde5/settings/general/web:ZTljMGY5NmYtYzZiNS00ZTVhLTkzM2UtMzZhMjBlNGYwZjNk) I've read that I might be enableing the auth in my google apis settings.

**QUESTION:**
I don't know where I went wrong. Do i really have to enable the api first in the google settings?
Is the auth setting in the header wrong? ( I tried with blank after Bearer)
I thought the auth process will be done by the server key.

This is just a test environment setup and it would be enough to see that the auth process works and the messages are sent.

Comment: Take a look at `getAccessToken` method in this example https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/master/messaging/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/Messaging.java#L45 
You have to first obtain an access token using your service account key. You have to enable Firebase API for that.

Comment: Thank you. i can get a token now. Is it correct that if I can get a token Firebase api is enabled correctly and I have nothing additionally to configure?